# How to compare AVPlayer Cureent Item with MPMedia Item?

Tags: avplayer, mpmediaitem

I am implementing an audio based application. In that I am using AVPlayer to play the list of MPMedia items selected from iPod Library. In my app I need to test 1 case, that is I need to compare the currently playing (from AVPlayer) with the list of MPMedia Items. How can I do this?

For easy understanding the following is I need:

```
for(MPMediaItems)
{
   if([MPmedia Item]== [AVPlayer CurrentItem])
    {

        printf("Do some action");
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried with the following code, but can't succeeded, MPMediaItem *anItem=[songs objectAtIndex:index];  NSURL *itemURL = [anItem valueForProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyAssetURL];AVAsset* asset = [[AVURLAsset alloc] initWithURL:itemURL options:nil];NSString * tracksKey = @"tracks";[asset loadValuesAsynchronouslyForKeys:[NSArray arrayWithObject:tracksKey] completionHandler:^{AVPlayerItem* item=[AVPlayerItem playerItemWithURL:itemURL];AVPlayerItem* nextPlayItem = [AVPlayerItem playerItemWithAsset:asset];
         if(nextPlayItem==[appDelegate.avPlayer currentItem])
         {
         }
     }];

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
MPMediaItem *song;
NSURL *songURL = [song valueForProperty: MPMediaItemPropertyAssetURL];
AVURLAsset *asset1 = (AVURLAsset *)[_avPlayer.currentItem asset]; //currentItem is AVAsset type so incompitable pointer types ... notification will occur, however it does contain URL (see with NSLog)
AVURLAsset *asset2 = [AVURLAsset URLAssetWithURL: songURL options: nil];
if ([asset1.URL isEqual: asset2.URL]) {
    printf("Do some action");
}
```